# Possible ways to write for comprehension to handle multiple options

Tags: scala

I have a function defined which return Option .

The below code works fine

```
 def func :Option[Result]= {
  (for {
    src <- ele2
    id <- ele
  } yield {
    src match {
      case "test2" => Option(id.value).map(_.take(3))
          .filterNot(_ == "de").map(id => Result(id))
      case _ => None
    }
  }).getOrElse(None)
}
```

If I remove `getOrElse(None)` I get compile error that `Iterable[Option[Result]]` does not match expected type `Option[Result]`

I want to get rid of `getOrElse(None)`.Is there a possible way to write the code

Comment: I think there is some information missing, what is `ele` and `ele2`? If `ele` is an interable, your code is ok to fail, as you are mapping their values, returning an Iterable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comprehensions in Scala is just syntactic sugar for `flatMap` and `map`. In some situations it is better to rewrite your for comprehensions using `flatMap` and `map`.

```scala
def func: Option[Result] = {
  ele2.flatMap { src =>
    ele.flatMap { id =>
      src match {
        case "test2" => Option(id.value).map(_.take(3))
          .filterNot(_ == "de").map(id => Result(id))
        case _ => None
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The other option is just extract logic from `yield` to function

```scala
def func: Option[Result] = {
  def innerLogic(src: String, id: Demo): Option[Result] = {
    src match {
      case "test2" => Option(id.value).map(_.take(3))
        .filterNot(_ == "de").map(id => Result(id))
      case _ => None
    }
  }

  for {
    src <- ele2
    id <- ele
    res <- innerLogic(src, id)
  } yield {
    res
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
val res: Option[Result] = for {
  src <- ele2
  if src == "test2"
  id <- ele
} yield Result(id.value)
```

Comment: I have some  filter logic and other logics inside
```case "test2" => Option(id.value).map(id => Result(id))```Edited my code

Comment: @coder25 Doesn't that just mean changing the yield in Yuval's answer to match your edit?

Comment: It says return type is Option[Option[Result]] and expected is Option[Result]
 ```val res: Option[Result] = for {
    src <- ele2
    if src == "test2"
    id <- ele
  } yield 
    (Option(id.value).map(_.take(3))
        .filterNot(_ == "de").map(id => Result(id))) ```

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul please have a look